# How do we run carouselview from MAC on IOS device?

Tags: ipad, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have downloaded a Xamarin solution zip from
https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

I tried running this solution on my MAC PC and deploying it to my Ipad. I encountered this error saying "could not find any available provisioining profiles for iOS" .

In order to resolve this I followed this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning

to create a free provisioning profile.

I have checked the settings of the iOS Bundle Signing settings of the solution i wish to run (carousel view) but although I do see that my profile is available for selecting and although I selected my profile, I still encountered the same error saying that they could not find any available provisioning profiles for IOS.

Anyone able to help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. A provisioning profile can only be used for a  specific bundle identifier.

The one in the Xamarin.Forms CarouselView demo is set to `com.slbdev.demo.ios`. Which (probably) differs from the one set in your provisioning profile.

In order to fix this open the `Info.plist` file and set the `Bundle Identifier` field to the one you used while generating your provisioning profile.

---

See bullet 5 in the post you linked:

> Under the General > Identity section, **make sure that the Bundle
>   Identifier matches exactly the Bundle Identifier of your Xamarin.iOS**
>   app and ensure the deployment target matches or is lower than your
>   connected iOS device. This step is extremely important, as Xcode will
>   only create a provisioning profile with an explicit App ID: